# Push and index data from a second json file into dataTable

Tags: jquery, html, json, datatables, getjson

What i am trying to do is append data from a second json file into dataTable.

The issue i am having is appending the data into the table, Then the data for each row to be the same as the name in the row.

example:

```
Position             Name         Symbol       Price       MarketCap       Change7d
    1           Bitcoin dogecoin    btc       243.967     3490594447.55     -2.96
    2           Ripple dogecoin     xrp      0.0107266    342270269.453     13.28
    3           Litecoin dogecoin   ltc        2.9611     118992556.35      -0.05
    4           Dogecoin dogecoin   doge    0.000190396   19018726.9507     -5.09
```

Should look like:

```
Position             Name         Symbol       Price       MarketCap       Change7d
    1           Bitcoin bitcoin     btc       243.967     3490594447.55     -2.96
    2           Ripple riple        xrp      0.0107266    342270269.453     13.28
    3           Litecoin litecoin   ltc        2.9611     118992556.35      -0.05
    4           Dogecoin dogecoin   doge    0.000190396   19018726.9507     -5.09
```

The data for dogecoin should match bitcoin.

i have a Plunker to show more of what i am trying to do here [Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5uaMbrK6CGoEJKGPmCXj?p=preview)

Thanks for any help on this issue im not even 100% sure if you can pass data like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$.getJSON("coin.json", function(json) {
    myTable
      .column(1)
      .nodes()
      .each(function(node, index, dt) {
        var slug = find(myTable.cell(node).data().name, json.coins);
        var item = $("<b></b>").html(slug.name);
        $(myTable.cell(node).node()).append(item);
    });
});
```

`myTable.column(1).nodes()` will iterate over each row in column 1. As it iterates search for the required object like this

```
function find(key, obj) {
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj[i].name == key) {
      return obj[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Here is a demo **http://plnkr.co/edit/4ktGkmPd0dWTPpRkAWCO?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks you that did it :) it was doing my head in.